Error 1 retrieving device properties for sdk gphone64 x86 64?
VS Code output : [ERR] Error 1 retrieving device properties for sdk gphone64 x86 64: [ERR] adb.exe: device 'emulator-5554' not found
any one can help ?
nothing to do just wipe data and re run without debug
iam trying since 10 hours please i nees solve it
1- remove java jdk 22
2- install java jdk21

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
